# Intern's pollUntil does not work with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, intern, leadfoot

I have a custom crawler that redirects to all pages in an application and takes screenshot. The page load works perfectly fine in Firefox. However in Chrome, the page does not load properly and as a result most of the screenshots come as blank.

```
return remote.get(newAddress)
    .then(pollUntil('return document.readyState==="complete";', [], 30000))
    .takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
        recordImage(newAddress, data);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`false` is considered a value by `pollUntil`. You need to return `null` or `undefined` if you want it to continue polling:

```
return remote.get(newAddress)
    .then(pollUntil('return document.readyState==="complete"||null;', [], 30000))
    .takeScreenshot().then(function(data) {
        recordImage(newAddress, data);
    })
```

From [the docs](http://theintern.github.io/leadfoot/pollUntil.html):

> The function should return null or undefined if there is not a result. If the poller function throws, polling will halt.